# Regex to find all methods calls in any language

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex expression, that will match all method calls in a given string.

Sample inputs and outputs:

`method1("key") // outputs method1`

`method1("key").method2("key") // outputs method1, method12`

`method1(method2.key()) // outputs method1, method2`

I tried following code,

```
String line = "public String = method1(\"param\")";
private static Pattern methodCalls = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+\\([^\\)]*\\)(\\.[^\\)]*\\))?");

Matcher mc = methodCalls.matcher(line);
while (mc.find()) {
   System.out.println(mc.group(0)); // expected method1
}
```

It works only for type `method1("key")` functions.

Comment: That is not possible. You cannot recognize dyck-languages through DFA's, thus you cannot get all (recursive) method calls through a regex.

Comment: @Turing85 Are there any other way to do that?

Comment: Yes. Through a parser.

Comment: Correction: you CAN extract the method names, but you cannot validate through a regex. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot extract *and* validate at the same time. Reasoning is quite simple: method calls include dyck-languages, and dyck-languages are not regular, thus you cannot validate some dyck-like string through a regular expression.

But if you know already that the syntax is correct, you can extract all method names through the following regex:

```
([^\W:.,()\s]+)\s*\(|::([^W:.,()\s]+)
```

Notes:

- I included the line breaks for readability. If you include them in your regex, it will not work. Please write the regex in one continuous line.
- If you want to use the regex in Java, you need to escape the `\`es)

[<kbd>regex101 example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/Dh0gQ7/1) [<kbd>Ideone example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ObFjlG)

For a detailed explanation, please refer to the [<kbd>regex101 example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/Dh0gQ7/1).

Comment: This works not even for type ```a("key")``` functions.

Comment: @Kaplan [Uhm...](https://regex101.com/r/Dh0gQ7/2) can you give an example String that does not work?

Comment: Under a method call, I understand the name of a method with the optional parameter to be passed. So you only need the method name: `a(` instead of `a("key")`.

Comment: @Kaplan that is exactly what the regex does. Please take a look at the provided examples (regex101 and Ideone). The method names (only, without parameters) are extracted, as it was stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

*this pattern finds the 3 examples of method-calls in Your question — only the 3 examples*

`private static Pattern methodCalls = Pattern.compile("\\w+[(](?:\"\\w+\"|\\w+\\.\\w+[(][)])[)](?:\\.\\w+[(]\"\\w+\"[)])?");`